# Adding SMB share to sidebar in OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, finder, smb, alias, sidebar

Is there a way to add an SMB share to the sidebar in Finder, such that when I click on the alias, it mounts the share and opens it up like a regular folder? You can do this in Linux and Windows, and if I recall correctly, OSX Lion.

It doesn't work on Mountain Lion (10.8.[0-2]).

Answer (score 4):

It works on 10.8.2 without creating an alias. You can drag the shared folder to the sidebar. It will auto mount after you have disconnected.